# How to map the Caps Lock key to Left Alt in Ubuntu +18?

Tags: gnome, 18.04, xkb

I've been looking for a way to solve the aforementioned problem.

I tried

`xmodmap -e "keycode 66 = Alt_L"`

but apparently the result is that the <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> key gets mapped to <kbd>Left-SHIFT</kbd>, which is not the intended behavior.
From my searches I understood that `xmodmap` is obsolete and I should use `setxkbmap` instead. However, I found it very hard to remap a key that is not part of the default options of `xkb` (e.g. I could map <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> to <kbd>Left-CTRL</kbd> but not to <kbd>Left-ALT</kbd>).

How can I use `setxkbmap` to achieve this goal?

Comment: Do you want CapsLock and LeftAlt to be swapped, or should LeftAlt now be an additional CapsLock, or do you want the CapsLock key have a different behaviour, or essentially be a dead key?

Comment: @emk2203 Thanks for your comment. I want CapsLock to be an *additional* LeftAlt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started considering the solutions from [here](https://beatworm.co.uk/blog/keyboards/gnome-wayland-xkb) and [here](https://medium.com/@damko/a-simple-humble-but-comprehensive-guide-to-xkb-for-linux-6f1ad5e13450), but I couldn't make them work.

I found the solution here:

> https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9635/how-to-assign-another-modifier-to-alt-key-for-x11

It achieves what I was looking for, although in a rather ugly way (I would very much prefer to create a new xkb option with this remap, but I couldn't make that work)

---

**Update**

The solution above doesn't allow me to keep two different keys for LALT. 
Instead, I followed [this](https://beatworm.co.uk/blog/keyboards/gnome-wayland-xkb) guideline with the following symbol definition:

```
// This changes the <CAPS> key to become an Alt modifier,
// but it will still produce the Caps_Lock keysym.
hidden partial modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "alt" {
    replace key <CAPS> {
        type[Group1] = "ONE_LEVEL",
        symbols[Group1] = [ Caps_Lock ],
        actions[Group1] = [ SetMods(modifiers=Mod1) ]
    };
    modifier_map Mod1 { <CAPS> };
};
```